# Changing figure layout elements during bokeh serve

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a hexgraph displaying a heatmap for my data. For this I use a ColumnDataSource containing the x,y information, as well as the values and the color for this item. Addtionally I provide a color bar to the hex graph showing the information which value will lead to which color. This should work for different data sets, however I am not able to update the color bar according to min and high values during run time.

Here is an example code (the simple myapp example provided by bokeh) where each button press should add a color bar with different values:

```
from random import random
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import Button, LinearColorMapper, ColorBar, BasicTicker
from bokeh.palettes import RdYlBu3
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from colorcet import CET_L18 as palette

# create a plot and style its properties
p = figure(x_range=(0, 100), y_range=(0, 100), toolbar_location=None)
p.border_fill_color = 'black'
p.background_fill_color = 'black'
p.outline_line_color = None
p.grid.grid_line_color = None

# add a text renderer to our plot (no data yet)
r = p.text(x=[], y=[], text=[], text_color=[], text_font_size="20pt",
           text_baseline="middle", text_align="center")
i = 0

ds = r.data_source
# create a callback that will add a number in a random location
def callback():
    global i

    # BEST PRACTICE --- update .data in one step with a new dict
    new_data = dict()
    new_data['x'] = ds.data['x'] + [random()*70 + 15]
    new_data['y'] = ds.data['y'] + [random()*70 + 15]
    new_data['text_color'] = ds.data['text_color'] + [RdYlBu3[i%3]]
    new_data['text'] = ds.data['text'] + [str(i)]
    ds.data = new_data
    color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette=palette, low=0, high=1000*i)

    color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=color_mapper, ticker=BasicTicker(),
                         label_standoff=12, border_line_color=None, location=(0, 0), orientation="horizontal")
    p.add_layout(color_bar, 'below')
    i = i + 1

# add a button widget and configure with the call back
button = Button(label="Press Me")
button.on_click(callback)
#show(p)
# put the button and plot in a layout and add to the document
curdoc().add_root(column(button, p))
```

However, the color bar is not added during runtime. I also tried to add it before hand, then it will be displayed but not updated.
How am I able to add a color bar and/or update it during runtime?

Comment: Please let me give you a hint: **1) always provide a minimal but runnable code** There are very few people around here willing to make an extra effort to copy/paste piece by piece your code blocks and adding themselves the required imports to eventually reconstruct your complete program **2) Limit and focus your code and your description just on your problem** Many programmers read the code and understand the functionality faster when looking at the code instead of reading a text describing the code that you left out. I suggest you to edit your question following this guidelines.

Comment: I changed the question up, and provided a runnable example. In the first writing of the question I already prepared this snippet, however I could not reconstruct the error where updates of my visualization will completely stop. I hoped maybe some expert could see my mistake when I provide my original code. Thank you for taking the time to read it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, move setup of the layout outside of the callback for the button and have the callback only update data.

Next, use the `linear_cmap` function from `bokeh.transform` to construct the linear color map. This function gives you a transformer to get the color for a value in the color palette.

Finally, update the `high` value of the transform in the callback

#### Complete Source

```py
from random import random
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import Button, ColorBar, BasicTicker
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from colorcet import CET_L18 as palette
from bokeh.transform import linear_cmap

# create a plot and style its properties
p = figure(x_range=(0, 100), y_range=(0, 100), toolbar_location=None)
p.border_fill_color = 'black'
p.background_fill_color = 'black'
p.outline_line_color = None
p.grid.grid_line_color = None

i = 0

color_mapper = linear_cmap(field_name='text', palette=palette, low=0, high=i)
color_bar = ColorBar(
    color_mapper=color_mapper['transform'], 
    ticker=BasicTicker(),
    label_standoff=12,
    border_line_color='black',
    location=(0, 0),
    orientation="horizontal")

# add a text renderer to our plot (no data yet)
ds = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=[],y=[],text=[]))
r = p.text(x='x', y='y', text='text', text_color=color_mapper, text_font_size="20pt",
           text_baseline="middle", text_align="center", source=ds)
p.add_layout(color_bar, 'below')

# create a callback that will add a number in a random location
def callback():
    global i

    i = i + 1 
    # BEST PRACTICE --- update .data in one step with a new dict
    new_data = dict()
    new_data['x'] = ds.data['x'] + [random()*70 + 15]
    new_data['y'] = ds.data['y'] + [random()*70 + 15]
    new_data['text'] = ds.data['text'] + [i]
    ds.data = new_data
    color_mapper['transform'].high = i

# add a button widget and configure with the call back
button = Button(label="Press Me")
button.on_click(callback)
#show(p)
# put the button and plot in a layout and add to the document
curdoc().add_root(column(button, p))
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you very much. Is there also an easy way to remove the color bar on update? I have one visualization of the data, which does need the bar

Comment: You can set the `visible` property for the `color_bar` in the callback e.g. `color_bar.visible = False`